# open a popup in the admin panel

Tags: php, html, jquery, laravel

What I want to do is this:

There is an **appointment** section and there is an **add appointment** button on this page. When it is clicked, nothing opens. I don't get an error, can you help me?

I tried to solve it with chatgpt, but I can't get any results, what am I missing or where am I doing wrong? can you help me?

Appointment.blade.php

```xml
<!-- admin/appointment/index.blade.php -->
@include('admin.static.header')
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h3 class="card-title align-items-start flex-column">
          <span class="card-label fw-bold text-dark">Randevular</span>
        </h3>
        <div class="card-toolbar">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_appo_modal">Randevu Ekle</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body p-5">
        <table class="table table-row-dashed table-row-gray-200 align-middle gs-0 gy-4">
          <thead>
            <tr class="text-start text-gray-700 fw-bolder fs-7 text-uppercase">
              <th class="w-150px">Kullanıcı</th>
              <th class="w-150px">Randevu Tarihi</th>
              <th class="w-150px">Randevu Saati</th>
              <th class="w-150px">Doktor Adı</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody class="fw-bold text-gray-600 fs-7">
            @foreach($appointments as $appointment)
              <tr>
                <td>{{ $appointment->user }}</td>
                <td>{{ $appointment->appo_date }}</td>
                <td>{{ $appointment->appo_time }}</td>
                <td>{{ $appointment->doctor_name }}</td>
              </tr>
            @endforeach
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@include('admin.static.footer')
<script src="{{ asset('adminassets/page/appo.js') }}"></script>
```

Appo.js

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 // Randevu Ekle butonuna tıklanınca modal penceresini açar
 $('#add_appo_modal').on('click', function () {
  $('#appo_modal').modal('show');
 });

 // Randevu Kaydet butonuna tıklanınca, ajax isteği gönderir
 $('#add_appointment').on('click', function () {
  var user = $('#user').val();
  var appo_date = $('#appo_date').val();
  var appo_time = $('#appo_time').val();
  var doctor_name = $('#doctor_name').val();

  // Gerekli verileri bir obje olarak toplar
  var data = {
   'user': user,
   'appo_date': appo_date,
   'appo_time': appo_time,
   'doctor_name': doctor_name
  };

  // Ajax isteği
  $.ajax({
   url: '/admin/appointments',
   type: 'POST',
   data: data,
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function (data) {
    // Eğer işlem başarılıysa, sayfayı yeniler ve modalı kapatır
    location.reload();
    $('#appo_modal').modal('hide');
   },
   error: function (data) {
    // Eğer bir hata oluşursa, hatayı gösterir
    console.log(data);
   }
  });
 });
});
```

footer.blade.php (I added these codes)

```xml
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="add_appo_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Randevu Ekle</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- Randevu ekleme formu -->
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="user">Kullanıcı:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user" name="user">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="appo_date">Randevu Tarihi:</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="appo_date" name="appo_date">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="appo_time">Randevu Saati:</label>
            <input type="time" class="form-control" id="appo_time" name="appo_time">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="doctor_name">Doktor Adı:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="doctor_name" name="doctor_name">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Kapat</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add_appointment">Kaydet</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can pull information from the table in the database on my appointment.blade.php page, and I don't have any problems.

Comment: Check your `id` settings. `#add_appo_modal` is the `id` of your _modal_, how is `$('#add_appo_modal').on('click', function () {` going to work when the modal isn't visible? The button to open the modal doesn't have _any_ logic in your script

Comment: How can I fix ?

Comment: Give your elements the correct `id`s. Use the correct `id`s in your scripts. Just in case: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/modal/#live-demo

Comment: Sorry, I got a little confused about your naming. Your `id`s seem to be correct (but misleading). The code you posted works fine as it is. Did you include the jquery/Bootstrap/Popper javascripts in your page?

Comment: I don't know how to add it separately. Can you help

Comment: Check your `admin.static.header` contains the jquery script.

Comment: Check your bootstrap version, since bootstrap 5 it is `data-bs-toggle` instead of `data-toggle`. This applies to all the `data-` attributes. (`data-bs-toggle`, `data-bs-dismiss`)

Comment: Did you load your admin.static.footer after you loaded jquery and bootstrap??

Comment: Try to change this : `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_appo_modal">Randevu Ekle</button>` to this `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" href="#add_appo_modal">Randevu Ekle</button>`